# How to stop introJS scrolling content when tour includes footer elements

Tags: intro.js

I'm implementing introJS on my website for a simple product tour (http://the.computing.cafe/). The behaviour of the tour is fine for elements fixed in the header but causes the main content to scroll for elements in the page footer. I have made a repl which demonstrates what is happening.

https://replit.com/@computinginschools/introJS

Click 'START TOUR'. The top three components behave as expected. However when the tour skips to components 4, 5 and 6, the main content scrolls. I don't want this to happen.

I've tried the basic options on introJS (scrollToElement, scrollTo, scrollPadding) but nothing seems to make a difference.

Can someone give me some tips on how to stop the main content scrolling for footer items please? I cannot change the structure of my website so this wont be a solution ;)